# Testing CodeIgniter controllers

Tags: codeigniter, testing

We are creating a RESTful API using CodeIgniter and I'm trying to determine how to create tests for the controllers. The controllers take some input from a client app, perform some business logic using one or more models, then output JSON.

The purpose of the tests is primarily regression testing-- to make sure that client-side engineers who are not principally web/php developers don't break something if they need to touch server code.

How would you test a controller action in CI?

I currently have two ideas:
1.) Create a test function/class that does its setup with the database then calls the controller via curl, simulating the behavior of the client.
2.) Don't test controllers, keep all logic in the models and write tests for the models.

Any thoughts on which will be more robust/easier to use? (or additional suggestions?)

Comment: I think there is a CI restful api library floating around somewhere, have a browse through and see how that works to point you on the right road.  sorry I can't point you to a link.

Comment: they got unit testing but im not sure if that's what you need. just posted in case it helps http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html

Answer (score 1):

As well as [CodeIgniter's own testing library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/unit_testing.html) (CodeIgniter 2) it is possible to [use PHPUnit with CodeIgniter with FooStack](http://www.knollet.com/foostack/). If you're using CodeIgniter 2.x, it's not as straightforward to integrate as it was in CodeIgniter 1.x but I have seen it done.

FooStack itself comes with example tests covering both models and controllers, among other things, and can give you a good starting point.

Another way to test your controller, which you've said is returning JSON, might be to use the Selenium IDE. This would allow you to run simple tests that check the required input returns the expected output without worrying how it's done. FooStack or the unit testing library would probably give you a more coverage and confidence though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want quality testing you need both.
One to test your code and how it handles with errors
and one to test how client itself would see potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate controller also through passing the form data to your test controller like

```
$_POST['name'] = 'testuser';
$this->CI->index_post();
$data = output();
# Decode Response data
$actualArray = json_decode($data, true);

$this->assertNotEmpty($actualArray['status'], 'Status is empty');
```

like this you can validate your controller through your test/controller.